# When No value is entered for multiselect attribute whose values are mapped with image, Broken image is getting displayed

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an `Multiselect` attribute `featuredetail` in magento 1.9.2.4.
Then mapping is done  with an image for every attribute value.

My phtml file for calling this attribute is:

```
<div class="feature">   

    <?php
    $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
    ->getAttribute('featuredetail')->getFrontend()
    ->getValue($_product));

      foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
            <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/feature/detail/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
        </a>
    <?php echo $value; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
```

Then I called this attribute to be displayed in `product-collateral` tab in product details page. When value is not entered for any attribute that is included inside the product collateral tab, the tab should be hidden. So I modified the `product-collateral` tab code in `view.phtml` like this:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
            <?php  

                    **if(trim($html)=="") continue;** 
            ?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This modified code is working well for the `description` attribute. But for the multiselect attribute with mapped image, when no value is selected for this attribute it is displaying broken image instead of hiding the tab.

What modification should be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
            <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/feature/detail/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
        </a>
```

to

```
$imagePath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/feature/detail/".trim($value).".png ;
if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
            <?php echo "<img src='". $imagePath ."'/>"; ?>
        </a>
}
```

Basically you need to put a file exists check.

Comment: When I put the above code rest of the code is changing to grey color and not working. Please help

Comment: Basically before img tag, you need to place a file_exists check on the img src Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/feature/detail/".trim($value).".png'

Comment: May be I did some mistake in the syntax as I haven't checked the code.

Comment: Is this syntax correct?   `$imagePath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/feature/detail/".trim($value).".png ;`

This is the line  affecting the rest.

Comment: I am not sure if the syntax is 100% correct as I didn't executed the code on my machine. I just used the above code and provide you the logic.

Comment: Basically file_exists check needs to be implemented before showing the image.